# How to Show all the data after applying Filter in Zoho Analytics with 0

Tags: data-analysis, zoho, bi-tool

I Have data of customers shopping with shopping date. Now I have applied a filter on the shopping date. But it eliminates the customers who have not bought something on given dates. How can I list all the customers whether they have bought something or not. if they have bought something then no of count and not then 0

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the Filter. Please Update Filter columns base on Requirements

Comment: That's what i want to know does zoho provides anything like ParaMeters such as AWS QUICKISGHT provides

Comment: https://analytics.zoho.com/open-view/1156972000001226026?ZOHO_CRITERIA=Year("Date")='2016'

ref: ZOHO_CRITERIA="(<column name/SQL expression/SQL function calls> <relational operator> <value/column name/SQL expression/SQL function calls>)"